# How to fail if <p4jresolve/> skipped any files due to merge conflicts?

Tags: ant, perforce

According to http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html#p4jresolve, files with merge conflicts are skipped. Even setting failonerror='true' does nothing in the event of merge conflicts.

Is the best way to check for merge conflicts to use:

```
<p4jresolve failonerror='true' forceresolve='true'/>
```

then check for conflict markers? If so, what's the Ant syntax to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `<p4jresolve/>` doesn't succeed (eg due to a conflict), `<p4submit/>` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

After you resolve normally, the files with conflicts will still require a resolve.  So you can run `p4jresolve` again with the `showactionsonly` attribute and see if it reports any files left to resolve.

I haven't tried it myself but that's how I'd do it just using the command line.